# A special case of the Riemann–Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

A special case of the Riemann–Stieltjes integral is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Differentiable_g(x)). The claim is that if $g(x)$ is continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$\int_{a}^b f(x)\  \mathrm{d}g(x)=\int_a^bf(x)g^{\prime}(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$
Is it that $g(x)$ needs to be continuously differentiable over ALL of $\mathbb{R}$ or just the interval $[a, b]$? For instance, $\log x$ is continuously differentiable for $x>0$, but not all of $\mathbb{R}$, so if $f(x)=x$ and $b>a>0$, we have
$$\int_{a}^b x\  \mathrm{d}\log(x)= b\log b- a \log a -b \log b +b +a \log a -a$$
$$=b-a=\int_a^b \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Why do you think an integral on $[a,b]$ should care at all about values of a function outside that interval?

Comment: The definition of $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)$ never cares about how $f$ and $g$ are defined outside of $[a, b]$.